# Can hover event operate with on() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

My code works fine when I run:

```
 $('.badge').hover( 
    function() {
        $('.js-main-header').hide()
        $(this).find('.js-badge').show()
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('.js-badge').hide()
        $('.js-main-header').show()
    }
); // end hover
```

But when I use the `on()` method, there is no hover effect:

```
 $('.badge').on('hover', 
    function() {
        $('.js-main-header').hide()
        $(this).find('.js-badge').show()
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('.js-badge').hide()
        $('.js-main-header').show()
    }
); // end hover
```

Comment: Could you use `bind()`?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl As far as i know `bind` does not support hover and `on` is the new API call for bind anyhow. `hover` is just a shortcut for `mouseover` and `mouseout`...

Comment: Thanks, I checked the documentation and found more info.

Answer (score 1):

The `hover()` method accepts 2 functions as an argument, one for mouseover, the other for mouseout. The `on()` method is being used incorrectly here, as you should be declaring it twice, once for the mouseover, the other for mouseout.

```
$('.badge')
    .on('mouseover', $.noop);
    .on('mouseout', $.noop);
```

Answer (score 0):

Official jQuery Documentation on [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Calling `$(selector).hover(handlerInOut)` is shorthand for:

`$(selector).on("mouseenter mouseleave", handlerInOut);`

If you need to call `mouseover/mouseout`, because you are using an earlier version then I would bind to those, else you could use the `hover()` function.

Comment: Generally speaking, there is definitely a reason to use `on`... it supports delegation and [custom event namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/), whereas hover does not. Even if you dont need/want to use delegation, i always urge people to use custom namespaces... Its just a good practice to get in to and should be considered mandatory if its a module or plugin youre making.